# mySQL table exists in command line, JDBC says the table doesn't exist

Tags: java, mysql, sql, linux

Let me start off saying this is my first time using JDBC and mySQL. I'm trying to use a .jar file (located on the server) to access my database. I can access and use the database fine through command line, meaning I can query, insert, etc. The DB I'm using is named "mydb", and when I "show tables;" while having mydb selected I get this output

`+----------------+
| Tables_in_mydb |
+----------------+
| Orders         |
| U              | Note Some of these tables were made during my testing process 
| Users          | but both U and Users are near identical.
| UsersTwo       |
+----------------+`

But when I run "SELECT * FROM U;", I get the info from that table properly.

However when I run my jar file (java -jar UserVerify.jar a a) I get the error Table 'mydb.U' doesn't exist. I am using InnoDB but I have not changed any of the directories, which I've read can cause problems. Currently this is running on a Linux VPS. The .jar file connects to the mySQL server using the root account so I don't think it is a permission problem (but I wouldn't be surprised though)

EDIT: I found the problem it was within my stored procedure.

Comment: Check that you are connecting to the right server and the right database on that server. Chances are you're not specifying the database to use when connecting, or you're connecting to a different server to the one you think you are.

Comment: I'm currently connecting to "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", where I have checked that mySQL is listening on port 3306.